# How to run node main.js from webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am messing around with typescript + webpack. I use webpack to re-compile the typescript "test.ts" code on every save. The script is compiled into dist/scripts/main.js

When I run `node ./dist/scripts/main.js`, I can see the console output of my script.

Is it possible to **run this command every time webpack recompiles** the script?

Thank you.

Here is my webpack config:

```
/* eslint-disable no-var, strict, prefer-arrow-callback */
'use strict';

var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  cache: true,
  watch: true,
  entry: {
    main: './test.ts',
    vendor: [
      'babel-polyfill'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/scripts'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015!ts-loader'
    }, {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
      }
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your package.json this rows:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "webpack": "webpack --progress --colors",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --inline"
  },
...
```

and after run your app like `npm start`

Comment: Hi, thanks for this suggestion. I currently only have the main.js file as an output of the script. So I assume the only way to do this is to be reloading an HTML file?

Comment: the code I am interested in running resides in http://localhost:8080/dist/scripts/main.js - so I only see the compiled javascript result..